# How do I retrieve what I return? (GraphQL query newbie)

Tags: mongodb, express, graphql

I wrote 2 resolvers (signup and login). They return a JWToken. In playground, I'm testing the functions and it won't let me make a mutation without specifying some subfields to display. They all are null and sometimes I get a "Cannot return null for non-nullable field users._id". I'm using express and mongodb.

```
const { UserTC, UserSchema } = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken')

const resolver = function () {};

resolver.me = UserTC.addResolver({
  name: "me",
  type: UserTC,
  args: { record: UserTC.getInputType() },
  resolve: async ({ source, args }) => {
    if (!args.record) {
      throw new Error('You are not authenticated!')
    }
    return await UserSchema.findById(args.record._id)
  }
});

resolver.signup = UserTC.addResolver({
  name: "signup",
  type: UserTC,
  args: { record: UserTC.getInputType() },
  resolve: async ({ source, args }) => {

    const user = await UserSchema.create({
      firstName: args.record.firstName,
      lastName: args.record.lastName,
      email: args.record.email,
      password: await bcrypt.hash(args.record.password, 10)
    });

    return jsonwebtoken.sign(
        { id: user._id, email: user.email },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1y' }
      )
  },
});

resolver.login = UserTC.addResolver({
  name: "login",
  type: UserTC,
  args: { record: UserTC.getInputType() },
  resolve: async ({ source, args }) => {

    const user = await UserSchema.findOne({email: args.record.email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect email')
    }

    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(args.record.password, user.password);
    if (!valid) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect password')
    }

    return jsonwebtoken.sign(
        { id: user._id, email: user.email },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1y' }
      )
  },
});

module.exports = resolver;
```

Here are the queries:

```
mutation {
  signup(
    record: {
      firstName: "Ben2"
      lastName: "Dormant"
      email: "Ben2.Dormant@gmail.com"
      password: "qwerty"
    }
  )
}

mutation {
  login(record: { 
    email: "nicolas.sursock@gmail.com", 
    password: "azerty" })
}
```

Comment: what do you want exactly? added more data

Comment: why do my queries not return a token? why am I forced to select subfields (token isn't one of them)

Answer (score 0):

I founded a bug, try like this because you can not use await in reutrn

```
resolver.me = UserTC.addResolver({
  name: "me",
  type: UserTC,
  args: { record: UserTC.getInputType() },
  resolve: async ({ source, args }) => {
    if (!args.record) {
      throw new Error('You are not authenticated!')
    }
    let result = await UserSchema.findById(args.record._id)
    return result 

  }
});
```